# button click event of code behind in javascript

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

i am trying to implement a button click event and trying to call it in my java script function without actually clicking the button.

```
protected void btn_hid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        string fbid = tb_id.Text;
        query = "select userid from users where fbid='" + fbid + "'";
        ds = db.SelectDs(query);

    }
```

now i want to call this function in javascript function as soon as page load occurs and java script is called.

```
function func() {

 alert("hiden");
 $(document).ready(function () {
                   control or simple html control
                   $("[id*='btn_hid']").click();
                  });
 alert("hiden end");
}
```

but this is not happening.Could you please tell how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
 btn_hid.Attributes.Add("onclick","return YourFunction()");
```

Nota : if your wish also register dynamically your script you can use

```
var script = "";
Page.RegisterStartupScript("YourkeyOfScript",script);
```

Nota : You can also use `OnClientClick` in your interface

Comment: I'am happy to help you Shalini

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. but It may be some problem. you can try with the alternate code.

using the following line of code.

```
__doPostBack('<%= btn_hid.ClientID %>', '')
```